# Handling nil value in Golang to skip struct element to process

Tags: go

I have a struct in Golang that I would like to pass to Mongodb to create filters. But how could I handle nil value struct elements so as not to add this struct element to Mongodb filters if the value is not interested in (don't wanna to use it in search criteria). What is the best practices?

```
filters := []bson.M{
        bson.M{"age": bson.M{"$gte": people.Age}},
    }

if people.MemberSince !=nil{
  filters = append(filters, bson.M{"memberSince ": people.MemberSince })
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue with the code shown?

Comment: Everything is allowed. You could make your code snippet reusable for any struct (read: `interface{}`) by using reflection, and just roll with it. There is nothing wrong with using your own head to find solutions to your own needs, and refactoring them if they ever no longer work well enough.